# Should umlauts be used in names, even if the person with that name didn't use them?

Tags: spelling, person-names, umlaut

I've recently come across a post (in English) speaking of Noether's theorem, where Noether's surname was consistently spelled as Nöther. But nowhere had I seen such a spelling of this name until this post. Even in [her own work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#/media/File:Noether_theorem_1st_page.png) she wrote her surname as Noether, despite Göttingen being written with an umlaut in the same sentence.

So I wonder, is it correct (in German) to write such names with an umlaut instead of the original oe/ue/ae, or is it hypercorrection?

Comment: It rather looks like her surname actually is _Noether_ and not _Nöther_. That's not unusual.

Comment: In general, it's not unthinkable to see well-meaning people being a bit overeager. They have seen multiple times umlauts being maltreated (maybe even ä/ö/ü to a/o/u) and just assume that something like "oe", especially in a German name, *must* have originally been "ö". But they are not always correct. When in doubt, you could also quickly check the respective German wikipedia page (where you can, if necessary copy the umlaut, should it be missing from your keyboard).

Comment: @The It would be interesting if there are any examples where the replaced Umlaut is wrong beyond of personal names, but ordinary proper nouns.

Comment: @Arsak No I am not looking for these kind of obviously wrongly spelled examples. We could also talk about the wrong interpretation of _b**ei**nhalten_ then.

Comment: Ich sag nur [fluege.de](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhWGIg4_HaY) :-P ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I wonder, is it correct (in German) to write such names with an umlaut instead of the original oe/ue/ae, or is it hypercorrection?

Names are names, and if a name contains an Umlaut written in the form of *oe/ue/ae* you can't simply replace them with *ö/ü/ä*.

---

A very prominent example is *Goethe*, which would never been written as *Göthe* by any educated native German speaker nowadays.

It looks like that at the time they were living the spelling was ambigous and both *Göthe* and *Goethe* were used ambiguously (thank's for [@Phillip's comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53442/should-umlauts-be-used-in-names-if-the-person-with-that-name-didnt-use-them#comment129924_53443)).

Though heself seemed to prefer the spelling *Goethe*, and that's what is used today.

---

> I've recently come across a post (in English) speaking of Noether's theorem, where Noether's surname was consistently spelled as Nöther.

I'd say that article you found is wrong about that.

Comment: Nur am Rande: Goethes Vater hieß Göthe, und wenn der Wikipediaartikel stimmt, war die Schreibung damals nicht einheitlich (»Obwohl Goethe seinen Namen stets mit oe schrieb, erschienen während seines ganzen Lebens Veröffentlichungen auch unter dem Namen Göthe«).

Comment: @Philipp Oh, Danke für die Info.

Comment: Was Beethoven not [educated](https://www.zeit.de/2012/28/Beethoven-Goethe/komplettansicht)? Or [Schiller](http://www.schillerhaus-rudolstadt.de/cms/website.php?id=/de/museum/rundgang/die_erste_begegnung.htm): "Göthe ist jezt bei Ihnen. Ich bin ungeduldig, ihn zu sehen. Wenige Sterbliche haben mich noch so interessiert."

Comment: @The He probably was a child of his time ;-)

Comment: @The That mentioning of _educated_ was a little cheap shot regarding the movie _"Fuck you Göthe"_ ;-).

Comment: That one also came to my mind.

Comment: -1 for the slightly overconfident (and thus somewhat arrogant) statement on Göthe, which actually happens to be wrong right in Göthe's case, as Philipp already pointed out. It think you should think twice before assuming people are not well educated just because they speak or write differently than you do.

Comment: In general, this is only one example that the spelling of names are rather instable over time. So also your claim "names are names" (suggesting they do not change) is just wrong. Take for instance _Steinway_ as an example. My own last name has been written with double -l some generations ago. And there are a lot of other examples for the fluidity of surnames.